# SQL Query For Selecting data from multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have Three Tables
named as
 tbl_savac_client..... Contains ac_no, Member_name,blance
another two tables are
one is :
tbl_savac_posting....Contains[tbl_savac_posting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZRqk.png)

and last table [tbl_withdraw_posting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWIq9.png)
I have Run an sql Query that gives me this Result[Unexpexted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xVL5.png)
I want the Result table Contains member_name,blance from first table and expected coloum data from another two tables.

my Sql Query is:

```
SELECT sc.ac_no, sc.blance, sc.member_name, sp.date,wp.date,sp.installment,sp.description,sp.mr_no,wp.wit_amnt,wp.description,wp.mr_no FROM tbl_savac_client sc left join (Select ac_no,mr_no,date, installment, description from tbl_savac_posting) sp on sc.ac_no=sp.ac_no left join (select ac_no, date, description, wit_amnt,mr_no from tbl_withdraw_posting ) wp on  sc.ac_no=wp.ac_no WHERE sc.ac_no = '$ac_no' and  sp.date BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."'
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * from (SELECT mr_no as mr, date as mdate, installment as ins,null as wit_amnt, description as des FROM tbl_savac_posting WHERE ac_no='$ac_no' UNION SELECT mr_no as mr, date as mdate,null as installment,wit_amnt as wit, description as des FROM tbl_withdraw_posting  WHERE ac_no='$ac_no') as t